# ActiveAdmin current user not shown in utility navigation menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using `ActiveAdmin` gem. I want to add a logout button in my utility_navigation menu. So in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` I write:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
    admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu, html_options: {}
  end
end
```

Then I refresh the page, but the menu looks strange:
[image]

When I move the cursor above the user icon, the menu pops up. But the position where there should be the user name is blank, and I can't move the cursor to the logout button (texted `退出`), because the cursor must move out of the icon.

I'm confused where is the user name row in the menu?

---

About the current user, I'm sure my `current_user_method` gives the right username. Here are the related codes:

In `active_admin.rb`:

```
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

And in `application_controller.rb`:

```
def current_admin_user
  puts "CURRENT_ADMIN_USER !!!!!"
  user = current_admin()
  if !user.nil?
    puts user.name
    user.name
  else
    puts "nil"
    nil
  end
end
```

When I refresh the page, I can see the username `admin` printed in the console line. So I'm sure I give the right `current_user_method`.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I thought having a logout button is [default behaviour](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9cffa4a8113405a6fb0a73b9ec725a1d55ed039a/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb#L177).